# Lightbox for text

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor tag. When it is clicked, I want a light box to open with a bunch of text (some thing like "read terms and conditions") .I looked up and most light boxes I came across are for images.

Is there a way I can do that vanialla javascript or simple jquery?

```
<a class="link" rel="lightbox"> Anti-Spam Policy</a>
```

I can put up a jsfiddle but, at this point I just have the anchor tag. I have no idea where to start from.

Thanks.

Comment: How about a [Jquery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)?

Comment: It is a good alternate. But I need to implement this as a lightbox. That is a requirement.

Comment: By "lightbox" do you mean "modal"?

Comment: Check this link: http://schier.co/post/creating-pure-css-lightboxes-with-the-:target-selector

Comment: Yes, A modal. I looked up on it and a modal is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you are looking for, using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="policy-text" style="display:none;">Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tri-tip qui cupidatat tenderloin cillum consectetur. Porchetta pastrami dolore deserunt kevin anim.
Aute cow cillum, sausage fatback enim in mollit hamburger ham nostrud labore meatball. Nulla enim jowl, jerky quis magna spare ribs ut pork loin...</div>

<a id="policy" href="#" class="link" rel="lightbox">Anti-Spam Policy</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#policy-text").dialog({
    title: "Anti-Spam Policy",
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 400,
    width: 500
});
$("#policy").click(function(){
    $("#policy-text").dialog("open");
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/ty1u9cod/)

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

It somehow doesn't seem to work on firefox  or any other browsers for some reason. I trimmed down my code to having just the code that is on fiddle you proivded, still it doesnt work on my system while it does on fiddle. I am not sure why.

Comment: @user3861559 Do you have jquery and jquery ui referenced in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the image with text when doing a lightbox by simply using a

```
<div>...</div>
```

in place of the

```
<img />
```

element.  Something like this:

```
<div id="my_light_box">
    <h1>Anti-Spam Policy</h1>
    <p>I won't SPAM you for nothin'--fersure!!</p>
</div>
```

So, it's just a matter of how to implement the link.  How about this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>

<style>
    body {
        background-color:blueviolet;

    }
    div#main_container  {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 30px auto;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 7px #303;
    }
    div#main_container div#content {
        background-color: #ffd;
        padding:15px 20px;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-align: center;
    }
    div#lightbox {  /* this is, actually, what creates the "lowered lights" effect */
        position:fixed;
        top:0;        /* Tack the dark 'curtain' to the upper-left corner... /*
        left:0; 
        width:100%;   /* ...stretch it across the screen... */
        height:100%;   /* ...and pull it to the bottom of the screen. */
        background:url('lightbox_bkgnd.png') repeat;   /* lightbox_bkgnd.png is a solid black 8x8 pixel bitmap with alpha set to around 75% to produce "low light" effect */
    }
    div#lightbox_content {
        background-color:white;
        border: 15px solid #999;
        padding: 3em;
        position: static;  /* didn't have time to test this in other browsers than Chrome, so this may not be necessary */
        width: 300px;
        margin: 50px auto;  /* to center it */
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/*url to a jquery.js implementation*/"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Hide the lightbox on load.
    $('#lightbox').hide();  // also could do a 'fade in' here.
    // Show the lightbox when the link is clicked
    $('#lightbox_link').click(function() {
        $('#lightbox').show();
    });
    // Re-hide the lightbox when the box is clicked
    $('#lightbox').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();  // and a 'fade out' here.
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_container">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Lightbox Demo</h1> 
            <a href="#" id="lightbox_link">Anti-SPAM Policy</a>
        </div>
        <div id="lightbox">
            <div id='lightbox_content'>
                <h1>Anti-Spam Policy</h1>
                <p>I won't SPAM you for nothin'--fersure!!</p>
                <p><em>Click box to close</em></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```